# PowerApps Flow - Edit .docx with Azure Function and save in Sharepoint

Tags: azure, azure-functions, powerapps, power-automate

I currently have a test PowerApps flow that

1. Populates a Word Document (Populate a Microsoft Word template)
2. Saves the Word Document in Sharepoint (Create File)

in Visual Studio I created a 'Azure Function' with an HTTP trigger. So I can make a

3. HTTP - Post (HTTP)

in PowerApps flow.

Now I want the Flow to send the created File (from Step 2) to my Azure Function

where I edit the document

and send it back to my Flow

and the Flow saves the edited Document in Sharepoint.

**Is such a scenario possible? How can I send the document to my Azure Function and from there back to the flow?**

In Azure Function the Document can be loaded for editing like this:

```
    public static DocX Load(Stream stream);
    public static DocX Load(string filename);
```

*edit*

I was able to download a file using a methode from here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/working-with-folders-and-files-with-rest

by using this: `byte[] data = client.DownloadData(endpointUri);`

My endpointUri in this case looks similar to this:

```
{https://something.sharepoint.com/sites/SiteName/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/SiteName/Documents/test/download.docx')/$value}
```

Now I tried to upload a file by using this: `client.UploadData(endpointUri4 , data);`

My endpointUri4 in this case looks similar to this:

```
{https://something.sharepoint.com/sites/SiteName/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/SiteName/Documents/test')/Files/add(url='upload.docx', overwrite=true)}
```

I receive this error message: `System.Net.WebException: 'The remote server has returned an error: (403) Forbidden.'`

Answer (score 1):

You can invoke the azure function with the below body :

```
{ fileName: '...',
content: '...' }
```

Consume the content in the azure function. But I doubt you will be able to send the file back to powerapps.

Alternatively, just a thought, rather than sending the file across - you could share the URL of the file as a parameter / in the request body.

The function then can use the CSOM / [Sharepoint API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/working-with-folders-and-files-with-rest) / [Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/onedrive?view=graph-rest-1.0) to read the necessary the files from the path - edit and save it back to the Sharepoint using the same (API/CSOM).

Also, to check (or like a call back functionality for) the completion of the azure function, you can have a timer control which checks (in an interval like 3 seconds) for status column in Sharepoint - provided the azure function updates the status column at the completion of execution

Comment: Hi there. Thank you so far. I have edited my thread. I have a problem uploading files

Comment: it 403 Forbidden access - so meaning you don't have permissions... since you are able to read, did you grant permissions to write ?

Comment: How would I do so? In Sharepoint I changed 'Manage Access' of my 'test'-folder. https://imgur.com/a/8g2ftPQ